# If A is linear operator $A:V\to V$,where V is finite-dimensional vector space,and $R(A)=R(A^2)$ then $\dim N(A)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know that is $A(x)=v$ for some $v$ from $V$.From $R(A)=R(A^2)$ I know that is $v=A(x)=A^2(x)=A(A(x))$,and from that $x=A(x)$ which means that is $N(A)$ trivial subspace.Is that prove correct?

Comment: what is $R(A)$? Range? Rowspace?

Comment: $R(A)$ is image of linear operator.

Comment: Meaning $R(A) = \{Ax | x \in V\}$ or that $R(A(x)) = Ax$?

Comment: Then you cannot conclude that $A(x) = A^2(x) \ \quad \forall x \in V$...

Comment: You can use `\{` and `\}` to show curly braces in TeX ($\{$ and $\}$)

Comment: Can you give me a example where from $R(A)=R(A^2)$ is not $dimN(A)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is matrix where is $R(A)=R(A^2)$,but it isn't $dimN(A)=0$. $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 2):

Saying that the range of $A$ is the same as the range as $A^2$ means that, for every $x\in V$, there exists $y\in V$ such that $Ax=A^2y$. You can't assume $y=x$.

The claim is false. Consider $U$ any subspace of $V$ and fix a complement $U'$. Then the projection $P$ on $U$ along $U'$ is an idempotent operator, so obviously the range of $P$ equals the range of $P^2$. The null space of $A$ is $U'$, which has dimension $\dim V-\dim U$, which is greater than $0$ as soon as $U$ is a proper subspace.

The easiest counterexample is the zero operator $Ax=0$ for every $x\in V$ (which corresponds to $U=\{0\}$).

Answer (score 1):

I provide a counter example.

Let$ A$ be the linear transformation which sends $(x,y,z)$ into $(x,y,0)$. Obviously $dim(N(A))=1.$ and $R(A)= R(A^2)=2$. Thus the claim is false.